# Storing SelectMany as IList rather than comma seperated string

Tags: episerver

I have an episerver block with one of the property being SelectMany as below
**[SelectMany(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(ItemSelectionFactory))]
public virtual string Countries { get; set; }**

Since this is a multiselect ,the default type for this is string which is stores the values as comma separated string.
What I am looking for is a way to store it in a list rather than string.

I came across an article to get an IList rather than string but I couldn't find property named **valueIsCsv**. I am working in Episerver 11 version & not sure if this property is available in a lower version but its definitely not in 11 or am I missing something here.
https://www.epinova.no/en/folg-med/blog/2019/enabling-out-of-the-box-editing-with-the-selectmany-attribute-for-a-ilist-of-contentreferences/

Is there a way to store the data in IList rather than string that is comma seperated.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Did you try declaring your property as type `IList<string>`?

It is certainly available in most CMS 11 versions.

Also, have a look at: https://world.episerver.com/blogs/bartosz-sekula/dates/2017/10/property-value-list/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ted. I did try declaring it IList & it compiles just fine but when running the application ,
it throws an error within the selectionfactory class
'metadata.Properties' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
The model type that it is expecting is of string type & so it doesn't accept IList.
Moveover, for the link you shared, that is used to define a list of type Property list. This is a for selection factory type. I hope i am making sense here.